# IBM Watson Assistant, Telegram and Python

Tags: java, python, ibm-cloud, telegram, watson-conversation

I think I am lacking conceptual knowledge on this topic. I have searched all around and I have not really found anything specific.

I want to create a bot in telegram, and communicate that bot with Watson Assistant. So all the logic is done by Watson, and the messages that go to telegram from a user, go to Watson, and the responses go from Watson to Telegram. **This is easy.**

The "middleware" or orchestrator, as far as I've seen and only if you want one (no need to have this), is in node-red, or node.js.

But what if I want to do it in Python or Java?
For example: Python if I want to implement a bit more of personal AI behind it, or Java if I want to use some parameters that the user sends to the bot, to do things (for example, buy a film in an api, or do something on a personal app).

I have seen libraries to create telegram bots, in Python and Java, but I really do not need this.

And the docs that IBM offers, as for what I have looked, are not useful to me on this topic.

So is this even possible? Am I doing a right insight on this, or am I complicating myself too much?

As long as it can be better understood, something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzOvU_DylZg&t=735s). But instead of Twilio, Telegram, and instead of Node.js, Java or Python. Minute 8:30 gives a graphical insight of what I am thinking.

Something like this: 
[image]

Comment: You want to do it in "*Python or Java*" but you do not want to use libraries to create telegram bots in these languages? I don't quite understand the question

Comment: I do not mind, but creating the bot itself is not a hard thing. It does not matter if it is in Python or Java, as creating a bot can be done even in Telegram. @Mark

Comment: If you want to "do it in Python or Java" like you mention in your question, just use the correct libraries for those languages? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Watson Assistant has SDKs for several programming languages plus a documented API. Thus, you can access it. The same goes for Telegram. What is the actual question? Please share your sources, what you have researched.

Comment: I have edited the question adding some things, so maybe it is a bit clearer now @Mark

Comment: I actually found some articles and your github in my recent research @data_henrik . So in this case, my knowledge does not really know how to integrate the watson conversation tool TO telegram. That is my main problem. I can use, for example, Python with Telegram, and probably Python with Watson, but not Pyton with Watson AND Telegram. Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM provides several SDKs for the Watson services in the [Watson Developer Cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud) GitHub org. The [Python SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/) allows to write chatbot apps with Watson Assistant.

My [Watson Conversation Tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) is such a Python app that shows both the V1 and V2 APIs and demonstrates how to incorporate client side and server side actions.

The following diagram from the [Watson Assistant docs shows the typical app architecture](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/index.html#about).
[image]

You would write an app that receives the Telegram messages, processes them, sends input on to Watson Assistant and channels the response back to Telegram. For reference, take a look at [Botkit Middleware](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware) which, written in Node.js, does the job for several communication platforms.